# Detectar erros e problemas potenciais (lint ou code quality tool)

Tags: php

É possível fazer uma analise (checagem) de um código PHP para determinar a "qualidade" da organização e detectar problemas potenciais?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lint_(software)

Comment: Antes de dar um voto negativo entenda o modelo da comunidade, leia: pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer e blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange e se tiver algum outro motivo pro downvote justifique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O PHP já fornece este tipo de ferramenta por linha de comando, pode-se testar a "qualidade do código" por linha de comando:

```
php -l <fileName>
```

Um exemplo no Windows seria:

```
D:\wamp\php\php.exe -l "D:\wamp\www\arquivo.php"
```

Além desta ferramenta existem outras maneiras de fazer isto conforme está resposta no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3601071/1518921):

1. [PHP Metrics](http://www.phpmetrics.org) - Apresenta uma visão geral e gráficos de qualidade geral, de acordo com diferentes métricas como mantenabilidade Index, métricas de Halstead, Coupling ou complexidade Cyclomatic.
2. [PHP Code Sniffer](http://pear.php.net/package/PHP_CodeSniffer) - Basicamente garante que o código PHP está em conformidade com a norma. Você pode escrever o seu próprio "padrão".
3. [PHP Unit](http://www.phpunit.de/) ou [atoum](https://github.com/atoum/atoum) - Teste Unit (testes unitários/unit são testes para pequenas partes de código).
4. [PHP Project Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/) - O N-Path e outras analises complexas para determinar a complexidade de partes do código.
5. [PHP Depend](http://pdepend.org/) - Faz análise estática de código em uma determinada a estrutura base (está estrutura é normalmente chamada de um AST (Abstract Syntax Tree)).
6. [ScrutinizerCi](https://scrutinizer-ci.com) (https://github.com/scrutinizer-ci) - Lista das ferramentas descritas acima

Também existe uma ferramenta simples chamada [PHPLint](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/) e pode ser [testada online](http://www.icosaedro.it/phplint/phplint-on-line2.html), o problema é que para versões mais recentes do PHP e phpDocumentor ele se demonstrou desatualizado, porém ainda sim é útil para testes mais simples.